# Swapping strings in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In T-SQL, how do I swap 2 substrings?

My URL column has:

```
https://www.host.com/test/last-first
```

How can I change it to:

```
https://www.host.com/test/first-last
```

eg:

```
https://www.host.com/test/smith-tim --> https://www.host.com/test/tim-smith
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: So you want to `replace` your string?

Comment: SQL isn't really built for string manipulation. It'd be much easier (for you) to do this in your application layer if at all possible. If not, then look up the functions CHARINDEX, REPLACE etc -- starting with [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms181984.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought `https://www.host.com/test` string same for all records.

Length of `https://www.host.com/test` is `27`

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'https://www.host.com/test/smith-tim'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@Value, 27, CHARINDEX('-', @Value, 27)) AS FullName, -- smith-tim
    SUBSTRING(@Value, 27, CHARINDEX('-', @Value, 27) - 27) AS FirstName, -- smith
    SUBSTRING(@Value, CHARINDEX('-', @Value, 27) + 1, 10000) AS LastName, -- tim
    SUBSTRING(@Value, 0, 27) + 
        SUBSTRING(@Value, CHARINDEX('-', @Value, 27) + 1, 10000) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@Value, 27, CHARINDEX('-', @Value, 27) - 27) AS Result -- https://www.host.com/test/tim-smith
```

Answer (score 0):

This has no length constraints  and always pickups last characters...

This can be optimised as well and used as scalar udf..

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string='https://www.host.com/test/last-first'



;with 
cte
as
(select *,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rownum,@string as string
 from 
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@string,'/')
)
,cte1
as
(select string,b.item,rn,c.item as itemtobereplaced
from cte c  
cross apply
(
select * ,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](c.item,'-')
) b
where rownum=5
)
select distinct 
replace(string,itemtobereplaced,finalstringtobreplaced) as finalstring
from cte1 t1
cross apply
(select '-'+item from cte1 t2  where t1.string=t2.string order by rn desc for xml path(''))  b( newvalue)
cross apply
(select stuff(b.newvalue,1,1,'')) a2(finalstringtobreplaced)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.host.com/test/first-last
```